# Meteor: Animating updated content

Tags: javascript, animation, meteor, css-animations, meteor-blaze

I have a Meteor app that is a basic scoreboard list populated by my users submitting their scores after playing a simple game. The scoreboard shows the top ten scores and obviously reacts to the latest data in the db. I want to know if there is a way to animate those scores in the list when they are updated and moving above / below each other (a little slide or something) rather than just popping in and out.

I found this package for animating content that is inserted or removed - https://atmospherejs.com/webtempest/animate and it is great, but offers nothing for updated content. I have seen some things about uiwebhooks in meteor but can't find anything about leveraging it in my project.

I don't mind if the animations are core UI from Meteor, CSS or jQuery, I just need to know how to call them. Simply adding and removing a class to that element would be enough for me to go on with.

I am a Front End Developer and new to Meteor so apologies if this is a bit of a misinformed post. Anything that could point me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your question.

I never worked with Meteor, but from what I know about animations - I expect that they are defined in a css file under specific class names, is that true?

If so, the easiest way to "restart" an animation, if you are using *keyframes* , is to add/remove the class responsible for the animation, from the dinamically generated element.

I found this small code example in the Meteor documentation:

```
animated.your-custom-class.zoomIn {
 -webkit-animation-duration: 500ms;
 animation-duration: 500ms;
}

animated.your-custom-class.bounceOut {
 -webkit-animation-duration: 2000ms;
 animation-duration: 2000ms;
}
```

This makes me think that the animations are indeed defined for specific classnames.

Try my suggestion and post an update if it solves your problem please :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply but the issue I am having is finding that hook or function that can do this for me when content is updated in the db. So from what I can understand, there is a hook that fires when content in the database is updating but I just cannot work out how to access it in my code to utilise it to add / remove classes.

In the meantime I have changed the code to remove the users current record and then add a new record with the new information. That way the animations work because the dom element is disappearing and reappearing.